# is it possible to play a song with a command block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was wondering if I could use a command block to play a song like strad, 13, blocks, and cat.  I figured you could use the `/playsound` command, but I am unfamiliar with the command and I need some guidance.

Comment: Have you tried to make this happen on your own?  Arqade works better when you attempt to solve your problem before asking us; we get a better question (because we know where you're stuck), and you get a better answer (because it solves your specific problem).  Everybody wins!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use:

```
/playsound records.<RECORDNAME> @p
```

For example, to play blocks:

```
/playsound records.blocks @a
```

Comment: Can this only be done with ingame resources? That is, I can't play any external music using this method without altering the game itself in some way?

Comment: @Ben `/playsound` can access files specified in `sounds.json`. You can add/play sounds with a resource pack, but you can't use the command to play any file on the user's computer.